# Pressing backspace button causes format number exception

Tags: java, sql, swing

When I press the backspace button, the following exception is thrown in my function:

`as format number exception as(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:)`

This is my code...

```
private void searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM SEARCH Where ID=" + Integer.parseInt(search.getText()) + "";
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            int id1 = rs.getInt("ID");
            id.setText("" + id1);
            String name1 = rs.getString("NAME");
            name.setText(name1);
            String surname1 = rs.getString("SURNAME");
            surname.setText(surname1);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
        System.out.print(ex);
    }
}
```

Could you please help to tell me why I'm getting this error.

Comment: 1- `KeyListener` is an inappropriate mechanism for listening to changes to text components, consider using a `DocumentListener` instead; 2- What does `""` represent as an `int`?; 3- I also be considered about running any type of SQL query inside the context of the EDT; 4- You're not disposing of your SQL resources (`stmt` or `rs`) when you're done, which could be leaking resources

Comment: search.getText() does it contain number or string, if number, try search.getText().trim()

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(search.getText())`  Consider using a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html) instead.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score -1):

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM SEARCH Where ID=" + Integer.parseInt(search.getText()) + "";
```

In the above line the `Where` should be in Uppercase letters `WHERE`

`String sql ="SELECT * FROM SEARCH WHERE ID=" + Integer.parseInt(search.getText())+"";`

Comment: This makes no difference and does not answer the question or the error, the `WHERE` keyword in SQL is not case-sensitive.